# Formatting a number as a currency value

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format currency using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682789/format-currency-using-javascript)

I am returning data from the serverside as numeric values, i.e.

```
value[0] = 1
value[1] = 100
value[2] = 10000
value[3] = 1000000
value[4] = 100000000
```

and so on.

How do I format this at client side so they look like this:

```
£1
£100
£10,000
£1,000,000
£100,000,000
```

Comment: What are you using for formatting?  Where do you need to do this formatting?  Is it HTML, PHP, or what else?

Comment: What countries do you need this for?

Comment: @Aleks G, Not sure what you mean by your first question.  I need to apply the formatting to a variable before appending it to the screen.  I am outputting html, and am using jquery.ajax to get json from the serverside, which sends back the raw values I need.

Comment: @Pekka, I need this for `en-GB`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try createing a function like this:

```
function Currency(sSymbol, vValue) {
  aDigits = vValue.toFixed(2).split(".");
  aDigits[0] = aDigits[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,   "$1,").split("").reverse().join("");
  return sSymbol + aDigits.join(".");
}
```

Comment: that works, but how do I remove the 2 decimal places at the end.  I do not need those.

Comment: @nami, just remove the number 2 in the second line. It should be vValue.toFixed().split(".");

Comment: thanks, this solution seems to be more suited to my needs than the duplicate links, which are way too long winded.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **plug-in for jQuery** that formats to currencies: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

**Demo available:** [Format currency demo](http://www.bendewey.com/code/formatcurrency/demo/)

Comment: Can I use this to format a variable, i.e. `var mynum = 10;`. then `mynum.formatCurrenty();`?

Comment: i.e. `£<td>" + mynum.formatCurrenty() + "</td>"`?